# Provide meta information to a class implementing an Interface

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'd like to provide meta information about a class implementing an interface and retrieve this meta data without instantiating it. That is to say, just by its type.
I was thinking of associating an attribute to every classes implemeting this interface and check at startup that it is the case for each of them.
This solution works but it's not very elegant in my opinion. It's also quite risky because the logic would resides at the API layer level instead of Application or Domain.

Example:

```
    public interface IMetaInterface
    {

    }

    public class MetaInfoAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string RedisKey { get; }

        public MetaInfoAttribute(string redisKey)
        {
            RedisKey = redisKey;
        }
    }

    [MetaInfo("IMP1")]
    public class Implementation1 : IMetaInterface
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    [MetaInfo("IMP2")]
    public class Implementation2 : IMetaInterface
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Caching
    {
        public string BuildCacheKey<T>(int id) where T : IMetaInterface
        {
            MetaInfoAttribute attributeValue =
                (MetaInfoAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(T), typeof(MetaInfoAttribute));

            string key = attributeValue.RedisKey + id.ToString();
            return key;
        }
    }
```

Would you have any other suggestion?

Comment: The most important part of this question was the least clear... Can you maybe add some more information around this "*I'd like to provide meta information about a class without instantiating it (ex: via generic method where the argument is constrained by the interface)*" - I am not sure I completely understand what you are trying to achieve. If you are just trying to get the metadata from the class, ie generic parameters and constraints, its likely all you would need is *reflection*

Comment: You can enforce the attribute with a code analyzer, also you could write tests for it, which would seem fairly logical also, and get the issue on commit or when your tests run

Comment: Thank you for the intervention but can you reopen the question now that I have edited it?

Comment: I have voted to reopen in light of more information

Comment: I've done things like you are doing (for example, providing a human readable name for the implementation class, and using it in the UI to let users know what something does (where "something" is the plug-in class they are looking at)).  The advantage is that the meta-info is right next to the actual class implementation.  Every other solution I can think of puts the information away from the implementation

Comment: I was the last re-open vote.  However, this is a very opinion-ish/recommendation-ish question and it risks getting closed for that reason

Comment: Well I was also thinking that maybe there is a c# or .Net feature that would help doing that.

Comment: It is not obvious to me why these classes are public.  Surely the intent is to make them internal and have a public factory method that does something with the attribute and returns the interface reference.

Comment: I have oversimplified my use case. I am doing some caching in my Mediator pipeline. If the type of the response implements a specific interface then I want to get some meta info to build my redis key and do some caching.